# Keeping file contents in variables in memory

Tags: javascript

I am interested in exploring the possibility to analyse directories with javascript source files in the browser in order to visualise them on a canvas. This would be done using Esprima to generate AST's.

This would mean that I need to read something like a zip or folder uploader and then start loading the files in memory.

The bottlenecks I'm facing is:

- If the bundle of source code files is large, this will probably cause memory issues. Localstorage isn't really built for this either.
- It cannot be done on the server because the user may not want to upload source code to a server, so it has to be done locally as a business requirement.   -
- Not really a good filesystem api in the browser with considerable size

What is an acceptable way of achieving desired result?
Can this even be done?

Comment: what are 'AST's'?

Comment: Abstract Syntax Tree. I might look into Electron for a desktop app instead.

Comment: What kind of analysis do you imagine? Would you need to keep the ASTs in memory, or just analyse file for file and store the results?

Comment: @Bergi The idea is to create AST's of all source code, and visualise them on canvas so they can be manipulated programmatically. Thinking about it, I would really need the source code files to persist on the client. Just closing the tab and losing all uploaded state would be a mess. Afterwards users would need to re-download the bundle with generated source code as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "visualise"? A canvas isn't large enough to show all the source code of an app at once, so I thought you'd display only some metrics. "*so they can be manipulated programmatically.*" - want to build a [structure editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_editor)? Then don't use canvas.

Comment: Oh no I didn't mean in this way. The idea is to visualise source code in different layers. For example top layer is modules, second layer shows apis,  third layer goes within the module etc. It's a crude idea, I'm checking the technical possibility. I can grab source code on the fly as needed;

Comment: @Bergi Erm, so yes it looks like the structured editor. What alternative would you suggest? What is wrong with canvas?

Comment: @Trace I'd try heavily-styled contenteditable dom instead, but really it depends what you want to build - more graphics heavy or more text heavy.

Comment: @Bergi It will be a combination of both. I will play around and explore. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [indexed db](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or [kv-storage](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/kv-storage) for large things that don't fit in localstorage but need to be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-database) to consider. It's not a wrapper around indexdb and seems perform better than sqlite. I have also used [LokiJS](https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS) in the past, but it's in-memory only.

Comment: Would you suggest it is required to study the IndexedDb interface first? Haven't used either of them before.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be for the browser.

Comment: TBH, I have never worked directly with indexDB and also used wrappers over it like [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) - really depends on the target platform i.e. electron should support realm.

Comment: How does Realm work in the browser if it isn't built on indexed-db or sqlite?

Comment: @Bergi, realm was suggested after OP said "I might look into Electron for a desktop app instead"